# Logic to use COUNT() to return number of matching values

Tags: sql

I'm trying to do something with SQL, teaching it to myself, and I'm unsure what to do next with what I want.

I'm trying to write a query into my DB (using just an "employee info" DB) that returns their name, a job they've worked on, but most importantly I want each job to have a "completion code" that tells about how the job was completed, and an int that shows how many times they've done a job with that specific completion code.

Right now, I can return all the info, sorted by person, job, then code, but I do not know how to get the count of each individual completion code (per employee). Here's what I have:

```
SELECT crew.EMPLOYEE_NAME, o.WORK_TYPE, oc.COMPLETION_CODE, COUNT(oc.COMPLETION_CODE) 
FROM   CREW_WORK_SCHEDULE crew, ORDERS o, ORDER_COMPLETION oc  
WHERE  crew.CREW_ID = o.ASSIGNED_TO_USER_ID
AND    oc.ORDER_ID = o.ORDER_ID
ORDER BY (crew.EMPLOYEE_NAME, o.WORK_TYPE, oc.COMPLETION_CODE)
```

But that COUNT in the select statement would just return the total number of completion codes, not the one for each code of an employee's job type.

Sorry if it's not perfectly clear, but does anyone know?

Answer (score 3):

Look into the group by statement, 
Group By crew.EMPLOYEE_NAME, o.WORK_TYPE, oc.COMPLETION_CODE

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT crew.EMPLOYEE_NAME, o.WORK_TYPE, oc.COMPLETION_CODE, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...)
```

And then replace your conditional with the ellipses. It is difficult for me to write it since I don't know your table structures.

Comment: No problem! That is known as a `subquery` btw

Comment: Not sure if you got the earlier comment asking a follow-up q, but I solved my issues, and got this working. Thanks!